# Integration of jboss narayana jta transaction in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jta, transactionmanager, jbossts

The jboss narayana jta  transaction manager is implemented in my standalone java application. can i integrate the transaction manager from jta to the hibernate. when i invoke the commit method of the jta transaction manager, all the changes done by the hibernate should also be commited. Pleaes help with example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the narayana integrated with the hibernate. The most important is that you have to provide a TransactionalConnectionProvider to work with the transaction manager. We have an example for this and you can find [Standalone JTA with Hibernate example](https://github.com/jbosstm/quickstart/tree/master/jta-and-hibernate-standalone)